# How to install Canon MP610 printer on Ubuntu 12.04 x64

Tags: 64-bit, printing, software-installation, canon

I'm running 64 bit Ubuntu, but my canon printer driver's only come in 32 bit.

### How can I install a Canon MP610 in 64-bit Ubuntu?

---

I've tried:

- Adding repository like it is written here:
  http://www.iheartubuntu.com/2012/02/install-canon-printer-for-ubuntu-linux.html

  - it did NOT work; the printer was installed but every print JOB goes somewhere unknown (probably to /dev/null)
- installing ia32-libs via 'sudo apt-get install ia32-libs'

  - This also did NOT work (it was already installed)

Answer (score 1):

<sub>Making a wiki because it doesn't seem like Arkadius is going to adhere to the site guidelines and move the answer out of his question.</sub>

---

1. Ensure you do not have any other canon drivers, either from canon it self or from other ppas by remove all other cannon PPAs you may have tried to install to fix this issue.
2. Remove any previously configured versions of your printer.
3. Remove the cnijfilter driver if it is installed:

   ```
   sudo apt-get remove cnijfilter*
   ```
4. Add the following repository:

   ```
   sudo apt-add-repository ppa:robbiew/cups-bjnp
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install
   ```
5. Install cups for cannon and gutenprint:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install cups-bjnp printer-driver-gutenprint
   ```
6. Restart CUPS:

   ```
   sudo restart cups
   ```
7. Add yourself to group lp:

   ```
   sudo usermod -G lp -a your_user_name
   ```
8. Add the  printer:

   - Click the Cog up in the right-hand corner of the screen and select Printers.
   - Turn on the printer and > make sure it is connected.
   - When the Printers windows appears, click +Add and wait a few minutes.
   - Your printer should appear within the configuration wizard.
   - Click the defaults and continue on. Cups should identify your printer.

---

Source: [Cups seems broken under 12.04 LTS...](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1967725&page=10)

Comment: note: I did not have to go though this to print via USB, just for network printing.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue and I found out that installing a similar version printer driver has the same driver.  Try and find a driver that has a similar version and see if the driver works.

Answer (score 0):

Does that link here not help you?

[Canon MP 610 - 64 bit - on Ubuntu](http://theseekersquill.wordpress.com/2010/05/03/canon_mp610_ubuntu_1004_64bit/)

In short you need these packages:

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs cups libcups2 libcups2-dev build-essential
```

Then you take the original 32 bit driver. You need to download from orig. webside.
You unpack this file and find three files:

> ```
> cnijfilter-common_2.80-1_i386.deb
>  cnijfilter-mp610series_2.80-1_i386.deb
> cnijfilter-common-2.80-1.tar
> ```

You install now with the following commandSSS:

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-architecture --ignore-depends=libcupsys2 cnijfilter-common_2.80-1_i386.deb

sudo dpkg -i --force-architecture --ignore-depends=libcupsys2 cnijfilter-mp610series_2.80-1_i386.deb
```

Then restart cups:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/cups restart
```

Then do a test:

> 5 Simple Steps to Setup the Canon MP610 Printer and Print a test page.

```
From the Ubuntu Desktop Menubar, Select:
System | Administration | Printing
Select Add to add a printer.
Select Canon MP610 when prompted for a device.
The Installer will attempt to locate a driver for the printer.  This may take a few minutes.
A dialog box containing details of the printer will be presented.  Select:
Apply
You will then be asked if you wish to print a test page.  Select:
Yes.
```

Congratulations!!!  You may now print using the Canon MP610 printer.

Comment: Thanks for fast answer. But your solution is NOT working. My print JOB is in state STOPPED. When I check attributes I see that "JOB-PRINTER-STATE-MESSAGE: /usr/lib/cups/filter/pstocanonij FAILED"

Comment: Also I can NOT do anything with apt-get because I get errors: Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 cnijfilter-common:i386 : Depends: libcupsys2:i386 (>= 1.2.1)
                          Depends: libpopt0:i386 (>= 1.7) but it is not going to be installed
 cnijfilter-mp610series:i386 : Depends: libcupsys2:i386 (>= 1.2.1)
[ ... CUT ... ]
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 13.04 64bit I only had to install the package `cups-backend-bjnp` to get the Canon MP610 working. There's no need to add third-party PPA's in Ubuntu 13.04.

1. `sudo apt-get install cups-backend-bjnp`
2. `sudo restart cups`

Now the printer would be automatically detected as "Canon PIXMA MP610". For some reason it will display the "Searching for drivers" dialog, but you can just hit Cancel. It had already automatically found the right driver from the driver database in my case.

Clicking the Print Test Page button successfully prints a test page with colors.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me:

1. Installed cups
2. Started printers via launcher
3. Selected my printer and clicked on forward
4. While being stuck on the install dialog, I killed dpkg via

   ```
   ps ax | grep dpkg
   sudo kill <nr-of-dpkg-process>
   sudo dpkg --configure -a
   ```
5. Then was able to select the driver and install it.