# What protocol should I use to wirelessly connect to a Cannon Pixma MX860?

Tags: printing, canon

I can't seem to get my Cannon Pixma MX860 to print over wifi.

I've tried:

- adding it via the add a new printer dialogue, but only my network laser scanner is found.
- going to canon's website for drivers, but there are none; it says to use the ones within my distribution.
- installing drivers via PPA, as mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75014/how-can-i-install-a-canon-printer-mp190-driver) but the michael-gruz/canon repository has no files for saucy.
- manually filling in the uri https information, but am unsure if I need to append port numbers and directory locations

  - the printer adds okay, and a test page seems to be sent out, but the printer screen goes black and nothing is printed (similar to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/97549/added-wireless-printer-for-canon-mg8150-no-print-is-produced) problem)
- manually adding the bjnp driver and entering it as a manual uri as specified [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/198363/how-to-install-canon-mp610-printer-on-ubuntu-12-04-x64/360325#360325), but have the same unknowns (port?, subdirectory(s)?) that i did with html uri addition and auto detect still does not work

### What uri formats are vailid for a Canon Pixma MX860?

Also of note: when I print via usb, it tends to mess up the first line of the first page printed on a separate page.

<sub>**Relaed:**</sub>

https://askubuntu.com/questions/382760/wirelessly-connect-canon-pixma-mg3222-printer

[How can I configure a Canon Pixma MG5300 to print wirelessly?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/187822/how-can-i-configure-a-canon-pixma-mg5300-to-print-wirelessly)

[How can I install a Canon printer or scanner driver?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75014/how-can-i-install-a-canon-printer-mp190-driver)

[Added wireless printer for Canon MG8150 no print is produced](https://askubuntu.com/questions/97549/added-wireless-printer-for-canon-mg8150-no-print-is-produced)

[How to install Canon MP610 printer on Ubuntu 12.04 x64](https://askubuntu.com/questions/198363/how-to-install-canon-mp610-printer-on-ubuntu-12-04-x64/360325#360325)

Answer (score 1):

Turns out bjnp does work when the package is installed via `ppa:robbiew/cups-bjnp`

See the community wiki here for a full how to: https://askubuntu.com/a/458619/171245